# Cannot insert value for identity in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting the error above when I call `SaveChanges()` using an instance of my `Context`. Now I understand what the error is pointing to, but I simply do not understand why it occurs for this particular situation.

The error occurs because I save an instance of the `TestMember` into the `TestMember` field in the Report class (which is the model for my table). Since `TestMember` is the foreign key this should not be a problem should it? For my own clarity I wrote raw SQL and explicitly put a **valid** int into the ForeignKey field and it worked fine. `INSERT INTO [TestMemberReports].[dbo].[TestReports] (TestMemberId,Date,IsSuccess) values (3, '2019-05-09', 0)`.

However when done in code like shown below. It throws the `SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'TestMembers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.` error. For the purpose of the question please assume:

`CreateReports()` is called from `main()`

### Code

```
public class TestReportService
{
    private TestMemberReportContext Context { get; }
    public void SaveChanges() => Context.SaveChanges();

    public TestReportService(TestMemberReportContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public void CreateReports()
    {
        var reports = AddReport();
        Context.TestReports.Add(reports);
        SaveChanges();
    }

    private TestReport AddReport()
    {
        return new TestReport { IsSuccess = 0, TestMember = GetTestMember("Member 1"), Date = DateTime.Now() });            
    }

    public TestMember GetTestMember(string name)
    {
        return Context.TestMembers.Single(c => c.Name == name);
    }
}
```

### Models

```
public class TestReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TestMember TestMember { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess{ get; set; }
}

public class TestMember
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TestRecipient> Recipients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "I would like to here from you" - this is asking for opinions, which is explicitly considered off topic on SO.  This question would be better suited for the Xamarin forums.

Comment: IDENTITY_INSERT is not about foreign keys but about auto-generating primary key values. Something doesn't add up in your question since when IDENTITY_INSERT is off your SQL query shouldn't work either since you do not provide PK value explicitly

Comment: @BohdanStupak very true. This is partially why I am very confused. Because from what I know, the Id field is simply auto incremented upon record creation. I will update the question to show the full error message, hopefully that sheds some light.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, this doesn't help much. The Id field is auto incremented upon record creation only when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON. So full error message just confirms my hypothesis. Could you please double check that SQL statement you've provided work when IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF? Also, if it works maybe there is some before insert trigger which does some black magic behind the scenes?

Comment: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestMemberReports].[dbo].[TestReports] OFF` I can confirm after placing this above my insert statement, the statement still executed and the table is populated. When I try turning it ON it actually doesn't auto increment, it tells me I need to explicitly set an Id. I have never had this issue before. @BohdanStupak

Comment: Sorry. My bad. That one is working according to spec. https://www.tsql.info/set/set-identity-insert.php Smh confused those options. So looks like EF generates id somehow behind the scenes. But since IDENTITY_INSERT is OFF it fails. Not sure how tho

Comment: @BohdanStupak Another concern I have is that the error says there is an error inserting value into the table `TestMembers` but the code only every tampers with the `TestReports` table? And even `GetTestMember()` returns an object which is already held witin the `TestMember` table. That's another thing throwing me off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this error in the future the fix is using a different kind of pattern to store foreign keys. Using SQL profiler I determined that when I stored a member object to be used as an FK in the Reports object, EF Core was infact running an INSERT query to my database (Hence the error message pointing to a table which is never called in the code).

### Old Report Model

```
public class TestReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public TestMember TestMember { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess{ get; set; }
}
```

### New Report Model

```
public class TestReport
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? TestMemberId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TestMemberId))]
    public virtual TestMember TestMember { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

This way whenever you want to store a `TestMember` object in a `TestReport` object you simply store the Id in the `TestMemberId` field.

And whenever you want to obtain a `TestMember` object from a `TestReport` object you simply use the `Id` as a predicate and use `.Include(x => x.TestMember)` in your LINQ (if you're using LINQ obviously)

I hope this helps you!